# Updating JLabel Dynamically causes GUI to distort - Works after resizing window

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have a GUI. The GUI is a JFrame that has a Panel[Gridbaglayout]. This gridbag layout has 3 different components. The middle component is a panel[GridBagLayout] which has the JLabel that I'm talking about. It also contains a JScrollBar that I am taking values from and updating the JLabel with as the user moves the bar.

The code I'm using to get the value and update the JLabel:

```
public class DrinkAdjustmentListener implements AdjustmentListener{

    @Override
    public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
        drinkLabel.setText("Percentage " + e.getValue() + "%");
    }
}
```

I understand when coding for Android, the main Thread is the UI Thread as well. With Swing I don't believe that's the case and I'm not sure really how to properly update the GUI. Is this fine and it's something else that's causing the distortion, perhaps the layout manager?

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image: After]

This is an some example code to run demonstrating what I was trying to achieve. Surprisingly it worked. I will have to make a longer example to exploit the problem.

```
public class Gui {

private JLabel jLabel;

public void displayGui(){

    JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
    jFrame.setSize(500,500);

    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));

    jLabel = new JLabel("Some Percentage 0%");

    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;

    mainPanel.add(jLabel,c);

    JScrollBar jScrollBar = new JScrollBar();
    jScrollBar.addAdjustmentListener(new MyAdjustmentListener());

    c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;

    mainPanel.add(jScrollBar,c);

    jFrame.add(mainPanel);

    jFrame.pack();
    jFrame.setVisible(true);
}

public class MyAdjustmentListener implements AdjustmentListener{

    @Override
    public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
        jLabel.setText("Some Percentage " + e.getValue() + "%");
    }
}
```

}

EDIT 8/15/2017, 11:30AM:
I found a workaround. I figured that since when I resize the window it seemed to repaint itself and looked correct. I just put jFrame.repaint() after every time setText would be called in the AdjustmentListener. As a side note it looked as if the entire gui was getting redrawn inside the "Options JPanel" as seen in the picture.

Comment: Please provide a short runnable example ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org)), so we can also reproduce your problem.

Comment: `Updating JLabel Dynamically causes GUI to distort` - I have no idea what "distort" means. That is why you need to post a proper [mcve] with every question.

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy There's my example.. Only problem is that it works.. I'm going to try and exploit the problem

Comment: @camickr I added pictures for before and after to show what the "distortions" were

Comment: Maybe you have custom painting and don't invoke super.paintComponent(...). Unless you can post an `MCVE` the "demonstrates" the problem I have no more ideas.

Answer (score 3):

In Swing, `Listener`s are executed on the UI thread. That is, it is safe to update UI elements directly from methods like `adjustmentValueChanged`, `actionPerformed` etc.

Only if update is initiated from another thread, you have to use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` and similar methods.